# Team Foundation Server 2013 - Build Service 404

Tags: tfs

I've successfullyish setup our Team Foundation Server. The only problem is the Build Service. I have created the Service, Controller, and Agent. It all runs fine for about 10 seconds.

[image: Running fine here]

After 10 seconds, a details link pops up for the service. and says "HTTP Code 404: Not Found", and the controller and agent image goes to stopped state, but still says Ready.

[image: Brok'd here:]

How do I go about fixing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a friendly URL for your TFS server? Or a load balancer?

Comment: Friendly. server.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your build controllers and agents you get to fill out the connection URL. If you have a different URL configured in the TFS Admin Console, for example a friendly URL, then the build services will be handed this as the communication medium.

So if your tfs server is "tfs01" but the friendly name is "tfs.mydomain.com" then the build service will be configured to use "tfs.mydomain.com" automatically.

It sounds like this communication line is not open.

Comment: When I configure the controllers, there is no option to fill out the URL. I am using a friendly name, server.domain.com. I've tried changing to 'Listen for Build Agent communication on' field to everything I could think of, nothing works, still the same error to matter what.

Comment: Can you connect to TFS from the build server on that URL?

Comment: Yeap I can access from that url, with changing the port of course.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well, on Visual Studio 2015. It turned out that the issue was with an outdated git submodule reference.

To see if you have the same issue, perform a git clone with the recursive flag, e.g. `git clone --recursive <repo url>`.

If any of the repository's URLs don't resolve, you'll find out which one so you can resolve the issue, potentially by modifying your `.gitmodules` file.